# Angular 5 - TEST-System build with all prod-features

Tags: angular, angular-cli

maybe the answer is super simple, but i tried a lot of parameters and don't seem to get it.

We have 3 environments in our Angular 5 application: DEV (our laptops), TEST and PROD. We didn't really use the environments up until now, that's why the problem arised only now.

For PROD we use --prod (which seems to be shorthand for --configuration=production) and everything is as expected, bundles are created and hashed and so on. But for TEST this doesn't seem to happen, leading to unhashed bundle-names, so bundles are cashed on the browsers of our testers, leading to all kinds of weird problems.

So how do i do a **full production build** with another profile than prod/production?

I tried stuff like "ng build -–prod –env=test", but that doesn't seem to do it.

We are on Angular 5.2.11 with CLI 1.6.8 right now and an update is not possible at this time (time/budget-constraints)

Thanks in advance,
Mario

*edit i found out now that *--outputHashing=bundles* does what i want, but i am still unsure about that. My test-build should be as close to my prod-build as possible. Is this and *--aot* really enough to ensure that? I find the documentation a bit lacking in that area - what does --prod REALLY do for you? If it is a shorthand for setting some other properties it would be really helpful to know exactly what this shorthand sets under the hood

Answer (score 1):

Try adding --aot to your build command, AFAIK this different style bundling is done by the ahead of time build. Production builds per default are AOT builds.

Comment: at first i thought this is correct, but it was due to still having the --prod flag in there. Unfortunately --aot doesn't seem to be responsible for the bundling / hashing